# Formato incorrecto en mi INNER JOIN

Tags: php

Estoy haciendo un string para armar mi INNER JOIN y estoy recibiendo por GET un ID ($id_emp), en mi INNER JOIN debo igualar el id_empleado con el ID que yo obtengo en mi sistema, tengo el siguiente código:

```
<?php 

 $id_emp='';


if(isset($_GET['ser']) && !empty($_GET['ser'])){

    $id_emp = $_GET['ser'];
  }else{
    $id_emp = false;
  }


  function getServicios($id_empleado){ 
    $connect = new connection();
    $connection=$connect->connections();

    $sql = "SELECT p.nombre_completo, p.direccion, p.telefono, p.correo, e.nombre, m.nombre_marca, p.fecha_de_visita, p.hora_de_visita, p.diagnostico, s.id_servicio FROM servicios s INNER JOIN prospectos p ON p.id_prospecto = s.id_prospecto INNER JOIN marca m ON p.id_marca = m.id_marca INNER JOIN equipo e ON p.id_equipo = e.id_equipo WHERE s.id_empleado = **$id_emp** ORDER BY s.id_servicio ASC";

    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);


    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {

        $direccion = $row[1];

    }

  }

?>
```

Parece que la manera en la que creo el STRING no es correcta. Me aparece el siguiente error en la linea del $sql:

```
Notice
: Undefined variable: id_emp in
/opt/lampp/htdocs/servicios-de-linea-blanca/views/technics/services.php
on line
18
```

Answer (score 1):

El siguiente formato me funciono:

```
$sql = 'SELECT p.nombre_completo, p.direccion, p.telefono, p.correo, e.nombre, m.nombre_marca, p.fecha_de_visita, p.hora_de_visita, p.diagnostico, s.id_servicio FROM servicios s INNER JOIN prospectos p ON p.id_prospecto = s.id_prospecto INNER JOIN marca m ON p.id_marca = m.id_marca INNER JOIN equipo e ON p.id_equipo = e.id_equipo WHERE s.id_empleado = '.$id_emp.' ORDER BY s.id_servicio ASC';
```

¿Como funciona?

En **function** modifique el nombre del dato que recibe por **$id_emp**:

```
function getServicios($id_emp){ 
    $connect = new connection();
    $connection=$connect->connections();

    $sql = "SELECT p.nombre_completo, p.direccion, p.telefono, p.correo, e.nombre, m.nombre_marca, p.fecha_de_visita, p.hora_de_visita, p.diagnostico, s.id_servicio FROM servicios s INNER JOIN prospectos p ON p.id_prospecto = s.id_prospecto INNER JOIN marca m ON p.id_marca = m.id_marca INNER JOIN equipo e ON p.id_equipo = e.id_equipo WHERE s.id_empleado = $id_emp ORDER BY s.id_servicio ASC";

    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);


    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {

        $direccion = $row[1];

    }
```

Y ya en el **string** cambie las comillas dobles por comillas simples e hice lo siguiente `'.$id_emp.'` para unir mi estructura en el string.

Comment: Por favor lee [answer], que bueno te funcionó y te animo a que cuando te sea posible aceptes tu respuesta para indicar que es la solucón, pero solo responder con código sin explicar como *funciona* esta solución se considera de baja calidad

Comment: Ya lo ajuste, ya iré mejorando.

Comment: Es mucho más simple: **el nombre de variable que usabas dentro de la función era distinto del nombre que ésta recibía como parámetro**, no hay más. Corregido eso, has de saber que la consulta se puede escribir así: ...

Comment: `$sql = "SELECT p.nombre_completo, p.direccion, p.telefono, p.correo, e.nombre, m.nombre_marca, p.fecha_de_visita, p.hora_de_visita, p.diagnostico, s.id_servicio FROM servicios s INNER JOIN prospectos p ON p.id_prospecto = s.id_prospecto INNER JOIN marca m ON p.id_marca = m.id_marca INNER JOIN equipo e ON p.id_equipo = e.id_equipo WHERE s.id_empleado = $id_emp ORDER BY s.id_servicio ASC";`  o sea, si rodeas la variable por comillas dobles, puedes meter dentro otras variables sin necesidad de concatenar.

Comment: Finalmente, quiero señalar que hay problema mucho más grave aquí, y es que tu código es altamente vulnerable a ataques de *Inyección SQL*. Un usuario mal intencionado puede filtrar por medio de la varaible `$id_emp` código dañino que puede afectar no solamente a la base de datos, sino a todo el sistema. Cuando puedas infórmate sobre eso y blinda el código contra ese tipo de ataques.

Comment: Gracias por la info, seguiré tus recomendaciones.